# How to handle data replication lag and event notification

Tags: asynchronous, amazon-sns, database-replication

We have a simple application, who upon every update of an entity sends out a notification to SNS(it could very well have been any other queuing system). Clients are listening to these notifications and they do a get of updated entity based on these notifications.

The problem we are facing is, when clients do a get, sometimes data is not replicated and we return 404 or sometimes stale data(even worse).

How can we mitigate this while sending notifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are Few strategies to mitigate this with pros and cons

1. **Instead of sending notification from application send notification using database streams**

   For example dynamodb streams ans aws lambda. This pattern can be useful in the case of multiregion deployment as well. where all the subscriber, publisher will subscribe to their regional database streams. And also atomicity of sending message and writing to database is preserved. And we wont loose events in the case of regional failure.
2. **Send delayed messages to your broker**

   Some borkers like [activemq](https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery) and [sqs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html) support this functionality, but SNS does not. A workaround for that could be writing to sqs queue which then writes to sns. This might be a good option when your database does not support streams.
3. **Send special error code for retry-able gets**

   Since we know that eventual consistency is there we can return special error code to clients, so that they can retry based on this error code. The retry strategy should be exponential backoff. but this may mean giving away your problems to clients. Also we should have some sort of versioning in place.
4. **Fetch from another region**

   If entity is not found in the same region application can go to another region or master database to fetch it. **NOTE** Don't do this. as it is an anti pattern. I am mentioning it here just for the sake of completion.
5. **Send the full entity in message**

   If entities to be fetched by rest service is small and there are no security constrain around who can access what, we can send the full entity in message. This is ensure that client don't have to do explicit fetch of it every time a new message is arrived.